# Is Strict-Transport-Security needed in error pages (400, 401, 403, 500...)?

Tags: security, web, response, hsts

I have a doubt related to the hsts response header. I'm developing a web application and currently I covered all the endpoints (with 200 ok responses)... this means that all the endpoints will return the hsts header when the response is 200. I don't know if it is needed for the server errors too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We usually include the HSTS header in all server responses no matter which HTTP status code is provided. In most cases this is easier to implement than everything else (either through config or one dedicated filter to rule them all). On the other hand there is no reason not to do it this way - the TLS channel has been opened successfully.

EDIT: Oh, and there are some other opinions on this too: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122441/should-hsts-header-be-sent-on-an-error-response